# Box around caption in figure

Tags: captions, framed

I am wondering if it is possible, in a figure, to put a box around just the caption and not the whole figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{article}    
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}     

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=6in]{foo.ps}

\caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture...}
%some command that can put a box around the caption
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** I added the `[width=6in]` on the `\includegraphics` command. It is a necessary part of the figures I'm including.

Comment: \fbox{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\caption{hello}}}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the command puts a box (beautifully) around the caption but moves the text from where I want it to be. See my edit above.

Comment: you can move the fbox eg  put \centering in the figure to centre it again.

Comment: And don't forget to use the optional argument of `\caption`.

Comment: Do you want this to happen with *all* your figures or just one? Should the box be of fixed width, or adjust to the width of the caption?

Comment: @Werner I want this to happen with all my figures.  The box should adjust to the width of the caption, but I think with the way I have things set up all my captions will be the same width, so making a box of fixed width or a width that adjusts to the width of the caption should both work fine.

Comment: You have a problem with your 6" specification, at least with the default `article` class.  6" is 433.62pt wide, whereas the `\textwidth` of the `article` class is only 390pt.  How are you wishing to address that?

Comment: My document has specific margin requirements, which I control in my preamble with the `geometry` package.  All my text is 6" wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following adjustment to `\@makecaption` places the figure caption inside a box that adjusts to the width of the caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\fbox{#1: #2}}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{#1: #2}}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}
  \caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture\ldots}
  \caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.
   I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.
   I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\@makecaption` was taken (and changed) from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls).

---

[`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) also allows for setting a caption style. So, if you're interested in a fixed-width caption, you can use something similar to the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{caption,graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{%
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering #1#2#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}
  \caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture\ldots}
  \caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.
   I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.
   I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The style is set to `\centering #1#2#3` where `#1` refers to the caption label, `#2` the caption label separator and `#3` the caption text. See section **4 Own enhancements** (p 24) of the [`caption` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

Comment: That works great.  However, both this answer and the answer shown in David Carlisle's comment on my question produce the following error when I run `dvipdf`:   `Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table... 
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary 
Error: Couldn't read xref table `.  The resulting PDF is displayed just fine with Okular, but I don't know if this error is a problem I will need to worry about.

Comment: @Joshua: I don't know what that might be the case. Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates this problem? If so, you could include it in your original post, or post it on [PastBin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Joshua Does this `\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4in,height=1cm]{foo.ps}
\setbox0=\vbox{\caption{I sure hope I can be boxed separate from the picture...}}\fbox{\box0}
\end{figure}` suffer the same problem?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No it doesn't.  However, I tried the answers given here with an example that is simpler than my full `.tex` file and there were no erros. I will make a MWE to find out what the true problem is.

Comment: Okay, this is bizarre.  So far I have been running a shell script I wrote that executes the commands `latex docname.tex` and `dvipdf docname.dvi` (and only those commands) and running this shell script produces those errors; however, if I run those two same exact commands by typing them and executing them myself no error messages are displayed.

Comment: I cannot create a MWE. I literally copied the .tex file I was having problems with to a new file and didn't have any problems with it and then renamed the problem-free file to have the original file name and the errors returned.

Comment: @Joshua: Why not use a `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf` workflow?

Comment: @Werner: Your proposed workflow produces no errors.